# Integración Mercado Pago con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mercadopago

estoy desarrollando un marketplace con PHP, MySQL y Mercado Pago y mi problema surge cuando quiero generar el boton de pago y el valor del token lo tomo de un registro guardado en una base de datos.

Cuando los usuarios se registran, se conectan a MercadoPago y grabo los datos del usuario y el token en una base de datos. Luego, al momento de pagar, quiero generar el link de pago y al utilizar el token desde la base de datos no me genera el id de preference.

Hice la siguiente prueba:
Si en la pagina de pago directamente pongo el valor del token:
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('APP_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

Funciona correctamente y me genera el link:
Pagar con Mercado Pago

Ahora si quiero hacer lo mismo pero con el resultado de la base de datos (o asignar el token a una variable), por ejemplo:

$Valor_TokenMP = 'APP_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('');
No me da ningún error, pero no me genera el pref_id, osea, el link me queda así:
Pagar con Mercado Pago

Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hola como estas? Pasando la variable debería funcionar, lo probé y al menos a mi me funciona.
Intentá reemplazar tu código:

```
$Valor_TokenMP = 'APP_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('');
```

por

```
$Valor_TokenMP = 'APP_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken($Valor_TokenMP);
```

Respecto a lo de guardar el access_token de usuarios en la base de datos, sinceramente no entendí el motivo pero no voy a cuestionar tu lógica.
Una recomendación es utilizar directamente en los archivos como se muestra en la documentación oficial:
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/integration